# Make a div auto fill exactly parent div horizontally

Tags: html, css

I want to have a footer in my html body that fills the body horizontally.

I have an html like this:

```html
<body>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

and a css like this:

```css
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body .footer {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

the documentation says that when I use `display:block` in a div then this div fills the parent horizontally by default. I don't know why but this isn't happening here! So I changed the css like this:

```css
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body .footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

now the problem with `width:100%` in addition with a `padding:10px` is that it produces a div bigger than the parent by 20px of course and a horizontal scrollbar apears!

Is there a standard way to accomplish that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three methods:

No horizontal padding:

```
padding: 10px 0;
```

Absolutely positioning on the right as well:

```
right: 0;
```

Or change the box-sizing of the footer:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

See here for more explanation on box-sizing: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: Excellent answer @Mike ! I will always use box-sizing from now on. Thank you!

Comment: might be worth noting that firefox and webkit browsers (safari and chrome) have pre-fix versions:

`-moz-box-sizing:border-box;`
`-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;`

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be because the div has a `position:absolute`. Try adding `right:0px;` to the style for `body .footer`. I don't think that will work in IE6 though if that matters.

See my jsfiddle (added red background to div for visibility): http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/BtnXe/

Comment: Thank you very much @jdwire. This is a good -weird though- solution!

Comment: By the way, if I change position to relative it seems to work with the `display:block`.